# Why do requests made for resources referenced by css files not include or recognize the basic authentication of the logged in user?

Tags: css, apache, basic-authentication

We have Apache's Basic Authentication turned on for both a subdomain and its related CDN. After successfully logging in to both the subdomain and CDN via the pop-up login, the page loads along with all of its css and js files just fine except for one resource. Chrome reports it encountered a 401 error while trying to load a font resource from the CDN. The CSS file that references it is loaded from the same password protected realm. When I look at the access logs, the entry for the font resource does not include the logged in user, thus the 401. All of the log entries for the other resources loaded by the page do include the logged in user. My question is: Why do requests made for resources referenced by css files not include or recognize the basic authentication of the logged in user?

Comment: There isn’t anything to be “passed along” here between any “files” (this is HTTP, there are no “files”, we are dealing with _resources_ here.) If your CSS is not loaded from the protected realm to begin with, you have not entered any credentials for it either - so _what_ would you even expect to get passed along to anywhere here? The only thing I would perhaps question here, is why you do not get a dialog asking for credentials, but it fails with a 401 directly.

Comment: Might be that because it is just a web font, it is not considered a “main” resource that would justify bothering the user. It might also be a CORS-related issue perhaps - but to tell for sure, your problem description so far isn’t specific enough.

Comment: The CSS resource is requested from the same protected realm as the rest of the page and the font. The Apache access log shows a request for  the page, the css, and the font. The log entries related to the requests for the page and the css show the basic authenticated user name in it ( `XX.XX.XX.X - user [22/Mar/2018:01:47:02 -0500] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1"`) while the log entry for the font does not ( `XX.XX.XX.X - - 
[22/Mar/2018:01:47:02 -0500] "GET /slideshow.ttf  HTTP/1.1"`).

Comment: Seems to be this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516192 Apparently still an open one, at least according to last comment from 2017-09-11

Comment: @CBroe Good find. I retested using Safari and Firefox. Safari loaded the resource and the entry in the access log included the logged in user but Firefox gave a 401 and the entry in the access log did not include the logged in user. So, browsers appear to be behaving differently on this particular issue.

Comment: Is your server sending an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for those web fonts? Firefox is quite peculiar about this when it comes to web fonts loaded in a cross-origin fashion, and I think Chrome might behave in a similar way. Check point 2) here, https://coderwall.com/p/v4uwyq/firefox-fontface-cross-domain-errors-workarounds

Comment: Yes, we are sending the appropriate access control headers for the fonts. Everything loads fine when we disable apache's basic authentication.